# Ubuntu internet not working with lower Wi-Fi signal levels

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

Ubuntu 14.04.3 not accessing internet traffic when Wi-Fi signal is at 2 bars of strength or less. It connects to the router/modem combo, but no web pages can be downloaded in any browser (or any network traffic it seems). Windows 7 can access internet fine on same hardware and low signal strength. Problem disappears when signal strength is 3 bars or higher.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` command is:

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1520 Half-size Mini PCIe Card [1028:000e]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
--
0b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1698] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02fe]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
```

Could it be driver related?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I have added the lspci output as you asked @Pilot6

Answer (score 0):

According to [b43 driver wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43) this adapter is supported by `b43` driver.

You can install firmware for this adapter by running

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

And you can activate `b43` driver by

```
sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe b43
```

After that `lspci -k | grep 0280 -A2` should show `b43` as `Kernel driver in use`.

If this driver works better, then I will add how to make it permanent.

Comment: I tried your fix. The firmware installed OK, but modprobe couldn't remove the bcma driver as it was being used. When I run 'modprobe -r' it comes up with this error message: "modprobe: FATAL: module bcma is in use" It then cuts my network connection and I can't reconnect and the bcma-pci-bridge driver is still there. How do I remove the bcma driver safely? @Pilto6

Comment: I have managed to use modprobe to restart the brcmsmac driver and regain connectivity. I am still unable to turn the bcma driver off and as such can't install `b43` 

More advice would be appreciated....:)

Comment: I m not quite sure that your device is supported by b43. It is just in their wiki. There may be errors.

Comment: I am somewhat confused. I need to uninstall the `bcma` driver before I can install anything else. There must be some way of doing this surely? The wiki's have cryptic commands and I am not familiar with this level of Ubuntu. i.e. I am somewhat a novice with Linux. I haven't managed to get as far as trying the `b43` as I can't turn off the `bcma`.

Comment: All the solutions I can find require removal of the bcma driver first before installing b43. @Pilot6

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar issue with my BCM4313, and it was due to the drivers in use ( bcma-pci-bridge, same as you ).
The solution was to install the official drivers, bcmwl-kernel-source.
You can find them on the repositories.

For more information check out this page:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx
It may help you.

Comment: You have another adapter and this is another case. Not all Broadcom adapters are compatible with `wl` driver. http://askubuntu.com/a/60395/167850  Your answer is wrong.

Comment: The adapter specified in question is different from which you are talking about ... this can create a confusion

Comment: Yes, I have another adapter, but the 43224 is also compatible with wl, see the official page of Ubuntu I posted.